# GitHub doesn't see file

Tags: github

I am using GitHub for the first time and I made it all to push my file in it, but it looks like it doesn't see the folders I made for the CSS, JS, and pics.

I tryed looking online, but nothing could answer my question. 
here is my GitHub page: https://github.com/onwuchekwa/onwuchekwa.github.io
as you can see, files are there, but in the webpage it doesn't work!
https://jak127.github.io/

Comment: Try accessing the correct branch, in raw form. So change `<img id="Picture" src="assests/Giacomo_D.jpg" alt="A picture of Giacomo Draghi done for the CIT230 class.">` to `<img id="Picture" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onwuchekwa/onwuchekwa.github.io/master/assests/Sunday.jpg" alt="A picture of Giacomo Draghi done for the CIT230 class.">` and so on.  Also it may be important to note that you're referencing two different user's.  https://onwuchekwa.github.io/# Seems to work.

Comment: oh... it was such a stupid mistake... sorry about that! and thank you for your help! it works great now!